# Check if dm multipath paths had previous errors like powerpath

Tags: rhel, multipath

We recently switches storage vendors and are now bound to DM Multipath for multipath management.
Does DM Multipath have a feature to see if any of the paths had a previous error on one of the paths.

In PowerPath you could see if there where any paths that had any errors since the last reboot/cleanup. There is a column where the errors are displayed. Like so (output is from windows verson, but does not differ from the rhel version we are using):

```
Pseudo name=harddisk1
Unity ID=CK0000000000001 [HOST1]
Logical device ID=123ABC123ABC123 [HOST1]
state=alive; policy=CLAROpt; queued-IOs=0
Owner: default=SP B, current=SP B       Array failover mode: 4
==============================================================================
--------------- Host ---------------   - Stor -  -- I/O Path --   -- Stats ---
###  HW Path               I/O Paths    Interf.  Mode     State   Q-IOs Errors
==============================================================================
   1 port1\path0\tgt1\lun28 c1t0d0    SP B2     active   alive      0      1
   1 port1\path0\tgt0\lun28 c1t1d0    SP A2     active   alive      0      1
   0 port0\path0\tgt1\lun28 c0t1d0    SP B3     active   alive      0      1
   0 port0\path0\tgt0\lun28 c0t0d0    SP A3     active   alive      0      1
```

Is there a similar output for multipath. Or do you need to go through all of the system logging?
I've already been searching the internet this last week, but it seems like there is non.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`multipath -ll` gives similar output:

```
# multipath -ll
eui.006a1354d146f94124a9376b00011010 dm-2 NVME, NoName Vendor
size=11G features='3 queue_if_no_path queue_mode mq' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=50 status=active
  |- 0:2:2:69648   nvme0n2   259:3   active ready running
  |- 1:5:2:69648   nvme1n2   259:12  active ready running
  |- 10:4:2:69648  nvme10n2  259:4   active ready running
  |- 11:1:2:69648  nvme11n2  259:13  active ready running
...
```